# How to suspend Cloud Foundry Org?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Under the documentation of [roles](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/concepts/roles.html), it is mentioned that:

> By default, an org has the status of active. An admin can set the status of an org to **suspended**...

However, I could not find any documentation on *how* this is done.
**My Question:** What is the correct API call for suspending an Org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cf curl /v2/organizations/<org-guid> -X PUT -d '{"status":"suspended"}'`.
See http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/263/organizations/update_an_organization.html.